# how to change this sql statement so it returns one row per widget

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql query:

```
select O.name, O.asset_no, A.name as attr_name, AV.string_value, D.dict_value INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/networkchassis_1503_detailed.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
FROM Object as O 
left join AttributeMap as AM on O.objtype_id = AM.objtype_id 
left join Attribute as A on AM.attr_id = A.id 
left join AttributeValue as AV on AV.attr_id = AM.attr_id and AV.object_id = O.id 
left join Dictionary as D on D.dict_key = AV.uint_value and AM.chapter_id = D.chapter_id 
left join Chapter as C on AM.chapter_id = C.id WHERE O.id IN ('5261', '5262', '5263', '5461', '5268', '5271', '22469', '5284', '14418', '5288', '5291', '5292', '5294', '5295', '20629', '20630', '5296', '5297', '5307', '5238', '22425', '22426', '5315', '5316', '22429', '22430', '5317', '22431', '22427', '22428', '5320', '5321', '5325', '5326', '13373', '5329', '14671', '14672', '22432', '22433', '8999', '648', '393', '394', '471', '395', '396', '1688', '1689', '268', '269', '5582', '5583', '5584', '5585', '5586', '5587') AND A.name in ("FQDN", "HW Type") ORDER BY O.name;
```

This returns two rows, per widet, one with FQDN, and the other for HW Type, like so:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| name      | asset_no | attr_name | string_value  | dict_value                         |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| widget1   | 1026857  | HW Type   | NULL          | HP             |
| widget1   | 1026857  | FQDN      | widget1.dd.com| NULL
```

I'd like to change the query so that I get one row, with both attributes specified.  Something like this...

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------+----------------+
| name      | asset_no | fqdn              |  hw_type       |         
+-----------+----------+-------------------+----------------+
| widget1   | 1026857  | widget1.dd.com    | HP             |
```

it's the dict_value field that contains hw type value, and the string_value field has the fqdn value.
I've been playing around with the query but so far, I haven't been able to  rewrite it to get the desired results.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

```
select O.name, O.asset_no, MAX(CASE WHEN attr_name = 'FQDN' THEN AV.string_value) as fqdn, D.dict_value as hw_type
FROM Object as O 
left join AttributeMap as AM on O.objtype_id = AM.objtype_id 
left join Attribute as A on AM.attr_id = A.id 
left join AttributeValue as AV on AV.attr_id = AM.attr_id and AV.object_id = O.id 
left join Dictionary as D on D.dict_key = AV.uint_value and AM.chapter_id = D.chapter_id 
left join Chapter as C on AM.chapter_id = C.id 
WHERE O.id IN ('5261', '5262', '5263', '5461', '5268', '5271', '22469', '5284', '14418', '5288', '5291', '5292', '5294', '5295', '20629', '20630', '5296', '5297', '5307', '5238', '22425', '22426', '5315', '5316', '22429', '22430', '5317', '22431', '22427', '22428', '5320', '5321', '5325', '5326', '13373', '5329', '14671', '14672', '22432', '22433', '8999', '648', '393', '394', '471', '395', '396', '1688', '1689', '268', '269', '5582', '5583', '5584', '5585', '5586', '5587') 
AND A.name in ("FQDN", "HW Type") GROUP BY O.name 
ORDER BY O.name;
```

I've modified the query to look like the above... but I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as fqdn, D.dict_value as hw_type
FROM Object as O 
left join AttributeMap as A' at line 1
```

If I remove the MAX() method, and just have the following query, it works:

```
select O.name, O.asset_no, AV.string_value as fqdn, D.dict_value as hw_type
FROM Object as O 
left join AttributeMap as AM on O.objtype_id = AM.objtype_id 
left join Attribute as A on AM.attr_id = A.id 
left join AttributeValue as AV on AV.attr_id = AM.attr_id and AV.object_id = O.id 
left join Dictionary as D on D.dict_key = AV.uint_value and AM.chapter_id = D.chapter_id 
left join Chapter as C on AM.chapter_id = C.id 
WHERE O.id IN ('5261', '5262', '5263', '5461', '5268', '5271', '22469', '5284', '14418', '5288', '5291', '5292', '5294', '5295', '20629', '20630', '5296', '5297', '5307', '5238', '22425', '22426', '5315', '5316', '22429', '22430', '5317', '22431', '22427', '22428', '5320', '5321', '5325', '5326', '13373', '5329', '14671', '14672', '22432', '22433', '8999', '648', '393', '394', '471', '395', '396', '1688', '1689', '268', '269', '5582', '5583', '5584', '5585', '5586', '5587') 
AND A.name in ("FQDN", "HW Type") ORDER BY O.name;

+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+
| name     | asset_no | fqdn              | hw_type          
+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+
| widget1  | 1026857  | NULL              | HP        |
| widget1  | 1026857  | widget1.dd.com    | NULL      |
```

As you can see, I'm getting closer to what I want as far as names of columns but I'm still getting back two rows vs. one.

Comment: Add `group by name` and adjust the `select` clause appropriately.

Comment: For clarity, what would the desired result look like? Also, note that your join on attribute renders an inner join. And lose those inverted commas around those integers - yuk!

Comment: @Strawberry, I've updated my post.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry, can you clarify via an example?

Comment: A sqlfiddle would be nice too - but look at something like `MAX(CASE WHEN attr_name = 'FQDN' THEN string_value END) fdqn`

Comment: @Strawberry, please see edit 1

Comment: You are still missing the word `END` in the first example after the edit. Gotta end that case statement.

Comment: @dot Look again at my example.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, i had to take care of some other business.  but I added the END to the CASE statement and voila!  it works.

Comment: @Strawberry, can you post as an answer?  then i can close this off.

Comment: You can accept your own answer! (or delete a frankly fairly banal problem) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work. I got rid of the output to the file as it's not really germane to the query result.  You may want/need to change the left joins to inner joins:

```
    select O.name, O.asset_no, 
         AV.string_value as FQDN,
         D.dict_value as "HW Type" 
    FROM Object as O 
    left join AttributeMap as AM on O.objtype_id = AM.objtype_id 
    left join Attribute as A on AM.attr_id = A.id 
    left join AttributeValue as AV on AV.attr_id = AM.attr_id and AV.object_id = O.id 

    left join Chapter as C on AM.chapter_id = C.id 
    AND A.name ='FQDN'

    left join AttributeMap as AM2 on O.objtype_id = AM2.objtype_id 
    left join Attribute as A2 on AM2.attr_id = A2.id 
    left join AttributeValue as AV2 on AV2.attr_id = AM2.attr_id and AV2.object_id = O.id 

    left join Dictionary as D on D.dict_key = AV2.uint_value and AM2.chapter_id = D.chapter_id 
    AND A2.name = 'HW Type'
    WHERE O.id IN ('5261', '5262', '5263', '5461', '5268', '5271', '22469', '5284', '14418', '5288', '5291', '5292', '5294', '5295', '20629', '20630', '5296', '5297', '5307', '5238', '22425', '22426', '5315', '5316', '22429', '22430', '5317', '22431', '22427', '22428', '5320', '5321', '5325', '5326', '13373', '5329', '14671', '14672', '22432', '22433', '8999', '648', '393', '394', '471', '395', '396', '1688', '1689', '268', '269', '5582', '5583', '5584', '5585', '5586', '5587') 
    ORDER BY O.name;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `[HW Type]` is not a valid alias in MySQL without a set of quotes around it.

Comment: @xathien i think you're right. i just tried it and it bombs

Comment: @kevin, the sql query is failing with  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join AttributeMap as AM2 on O.objtype_id = AM2.objtype_id  left join Attrib' at line 1

Comment: sorry.  I normally work with SqlServer. Forgot to put my MySql hat on

Comment: @kevin, i'm sorry to report that it doesn't work.  I'm getting a whole bunch of rows now per widget instead of just 2

Comment: Sorry, then I would need more information about your tables and the information they contain before I can help more

Answer (score 0):

Slightly rearranging Kevin's answer to put the criteria in the right places and renaming tables to make things a little more clear. To avoid the sin of excessive left joins, this assumes that your desired Object rows are *guaranteed* to have an AttributeMap and that AttributeMap at least contains the two Attributes you want. If this isn't the case, swap the `JOIN`s for `LEFT JOIN`s. Also, I removed the `Chapter` join because it seems you're not actually doing anything with it.

```
SELECT O.name, O.asset_no,
    FQDN_AV.string_value as FQDN,
    HWType_D.dict_value as "HW Type"
FROM Object as O

-- This section will cascade joins to get the FQDN value
JOIN AttributeMap as FQDN_AM ON O.objtype_id = FQDN_AM.objtype_id
JOIN Attribute as FQDN_A ON FQDN_AM.attr_id = FQDN_A.id AND FQDN_A.name = 'FQDN'
JOIN AttributeValue as FQDN_AV ON FQDN_AV.attr_id = FQDN_AM.attr_id AND FQDN_AV.object_id = O.id

-- This section will cascade joins to get the HW Type value    
JOIN AttributeMap as HWType_AM O.objtype_id = HWType_AM.objtype_id
JOIN Attribute HWType_A ON HWType_AM.attr_id = HWType_A.id AND HWType_A.name = 'HW Type'
JOIN AttributeValue HWType_AV ON HWType_AV.attr_id = HWType_AM.attr_id AND HWType_AV.object_id = O.id
JOIN Dictionary HWType_D ON HWType_D.dict_key = HWType_AV.uint_value AND HWType_AM.chapter_id = HWType_D.chapter_id

-- Apply the filter and order
WHERE O.id IN ('5261', '5262', '5263', '5461', '5268', '5271', '22469', '5284', '14418', '5288', '5291', '5292', '5294', '5295', '20629', '20630', '5296', '5297', '5307', '5238', '22425', '22426', '5315', '5316', '22429', '22430', '5317', '22431', '22427', '22428', '5320', '5321', '5325', '5326', '13373', '5329', '14671', '14672', '22432', '22433', '8999', '648', '393', '394', '471', '395', '396', '1688', '1689', '268', '269', '5582', '5583', '5584', '5585', '5586', '5587')
ORDER BY O.name;
```

Hope this works out better. Enjoy!